# Is this translation for “If I cannot move Heaven, I will raise Hell.” correct?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, aeneis

I want to make sure this is the correct translation for “If I cannot move Heaven, I will raise Hell.” Flectere si nequeo superos, Acheronta noveno.

Answer (score 7):

The last word is wrong, it should be *movebo*. Then it is an exact quote from Vergil's epic [Aeneid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeneid) ([liber VII, 312](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/vergil/aen7.shtml)), one of the most famous works in the Latin language, and in world literature.

It does indeed roughly mean “If I cannot move heaven, I will raise hell.” More literally: If I cannot bend heaven to my will, make heaven do my bidding, etc., I will move, set into motion, rouse hell.

Note that for heaven and hell, Vergil did not use words which mean exactly that; he thought in different terms altogether. For “heaven,” you actually have *superi*, which are “those above” (i.e., the gods above). For “hell,” you have *Acheron*, which is [a pretty harmless river in Greece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acheron), but in ancient mythology, this river was closely associated with the underworld (the realm of the dead), and for Vergil in particular, with Tartarus, a deep abyss and site of torment.